# List is giving repited value

Tags: android, listview

I have a list and i am adding a value using `add(int,Object)` method but when i am retrieving values using `get(int)` method i  am getting same values that is the last added values

Can anyone give proper suggestion ?
see code.

public static List getCompanyName(String user_id) {

```
    List<CustomerList> fetchDatefromID = new ArrayList<CustomerList>();
    CustomerList tempProgram = new CustomerList();
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "" + user_id));

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "https://erestaurantonline.co.uk/kernow_mobile/customer_search.php?");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            if (json_data.getString("company") != null) {
                tempProgram.setCompanyName(json_data.getString("company"));
                tempProgram.setID(json_data.getString("id"));
                fetchDatefromID.add(i, tempProgram);
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fetchDatefromID.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("log_tag","DataMy  :  "+fetchDatefromID.get(i).getCompanyName().toString());
    }
    return fetchDatefromID;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if (json_data.getString("company") != null) {
                tempProgram.setCompanyName(json_data.getString("company"));
                tempProgram.setID(json_data.getString("id"));
                fetchDatefromID.add(i, tempProgram);
            }
```

With

```
if (json_data.getString("company") != null) {
                tempProgram = new CustomerList();
                tempProgram.setCompanyName(json_data.getString("company"));
                tempProgram.setID(json_data.getString("id"));
                fetchDatefromID.add(i, tempProgram);
            }
```

Otherwise every item in your list is referencing the same object, and therefore will always contain whatever data you put into it last.